# Using the standard contact structure of $\mathbb R^{2n+1}$ on $S^{2n+1}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, contact-topology

The standard contact structure on $\mathbb R^{2n+1}$ is given by

$$ \alpha = dz + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i dy_i$$

And the standard contact structure on $S^{2n+1}$ is given by

$$ \beta = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i dy_i - y_i dx_i$$

For $n=1$ we get $\alpha = dz + x dy$ and $\beta = xdy - y dx + y dz - z dy$.

> Is it possible to use the standard contact structure $\alpha$ on
>    $S^{2n+1}$? For example, does $\alpha = dz + x dy$ define a contact structure on $S^1$?

It is not clear to me why it would not. But if it did there would be no need to define a different contact form for the sphere.

Comment: Since $S^{2n + 1}$ is not contained in $\mathbf{R}^{2n+1}$, there's no way to restrict. The sphere _is_ the one-point compactification of Euclidean space, but $\alpha$ doesn't extend continuously at infinity after stereographic projection. So...the burden of proof is on you to suggest a way to transfer one contact structure to the other manifold. :) (Your local expression for $\beta$ when $n = 1$ is not OK, incidentally; you need four variables, since $S^{3} \subset \mathbf{R}^{4}$.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you so much for your comment. How do I see whether a given differential form does or does not extend continuously at infinity? Does it mean the limit of $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\to \infty$ would cause $\alpha (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ to be undefined?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I'm googling for "differential form extends continuously at infinity" and "differential form after compactification" but neither yields any hits.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I see. Is there something like an "induced" contact structure? If $S^{-1}$ is inverse stereographic projection then $S^{-1}\circ \alpha$ is the contact form on the sphere we get from restricting the contact form on $\mathbb R^n$? And then the reason why this is not a contact form on the sphere is because it's missing one point (the north pole)?

Comment: Generally, perform the change of coordinates $X := (x_{i}, y_{i}, z) \mapsto \frac{1}{\|X\|^{2}}X$ and look near the origin. In this situation, it's "geometrically clear" [TM] that the kernels of $\alpha$ (the field of hyperplanes with normal vector $(0, x_{i}, 1)$ at $X$) point in different directions along sets $x_{i} = \text{const}$.

Comment: Your last comment is basically the issue; I'm claiming the pullback of $\alpha$ to the sphere doesn't extend over the north pole.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you. But now your penultimate comment seems to contradict that: there you suggest I look at points near the origin. But also the map seems to be the projection onto the sphere so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40249/discussion-between-self-learner-and-andrew-d-hwang).

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Oh no, sorry, I accidentally clicked the link to move to chat. I just wanted to add another comment: Is it then true that a diffeomorphism (or other sufficiently nice map) will map a contact structure on one manifold to a contact structure on another?

Comment: Looking "near infinity" in Euclidean space amounts to looking at the origin _after inversion_, or looking at the north pole of the sphere after stereographic projection. :) Regarding your last question, "yes": If $f:M \to N$ is a diffeomorphism between $(2n+1)$-manifolds and $\alpha$ is a (local) $1$-form on $N$ defining a contact structure (so $\alpha \wedge (d\alpha)^{n}$ is non-vanishing), then $f^{*}\alpha$ is easily checked to define a contact structure on $M$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I believe to have found a way to use the contact structure on some $\mathbb R^n$ on a sphere: by moving up the dimension. For example, on $\mathbb R^5$ the standard contact structure is $$ \alpha = dz + \sum_{j=1}^2 x_j dy_j$$
Now since $S^3$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^5$ we can use this structure as is on $S^3$. This works, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, $\alpha$ vanishes along the great circle where $x_{1} = x_{2} = 0$ in $S^{3}$, so it has three-dimensional kernel there, and consequently doesn't define a contact structure. :)

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by A. Hwang, there is no way to build the standard contact form $\alpha_{\textrm{sph}}$ of the $S^{2n+1}$ from the standard contact structure of $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$, the reason being that $S^{2n+1}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$.

However, one can construct $\alpha_{\mathrm{sph}}$ from the symplectic structure of $\mathbb{R}^{2n+2}$ and this is a rather general process.

> **Definition.** Let $(V,\omega)$ be a [symplectic manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold), then a vector field $X$ of $V$ is said to be a *Liouville vector field* if and only if the [Lie derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative) of $\omega$ along $X$ is equal to $\omega$, namely $\mathcal{L}_X\omega=\omega$.

**Geometric interpretation.** The vector field $X$ is Liouville if and only if its [local flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(mathematics)) expands $\omega$.

**Remark.** Since $\omega$ is closed, from the Cartan's formula, this is equivalent to $\mathrm{d}(i_X\omega)=\omega$.

Now, here is the link with contact geometry:

> **Theorem.** Let $(V,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold, $X$ be a Liouville vector field and $M$ be a hypersurface. Assume that $X$ is transverse to $M$, then $\alpha:=i_X\omega$ is contact form on $M$.

**Remark.** To be strictly correct, one owes to consider $i^*\alpha$, where $i\colon M\hookrightarrow V$, but this is just a waste of notation since the pullback commutes with the exterior product and derivative.

**Remark.** In this setting, $\mathrm{d}\alpha=\omega_{\vert M}$ and $M$ is said to be an hypersurface of contact-type of $(V,\omega)$.

**Proof.** Let $2(n+1)$ be the dimension of $V$, then $M$ has dimension $2n+1$. Notice that one has:
$$\alpha\wedge(\mathrm{d}\alpha)^n=i_X\omega\wedge w^n=\frac{1}{n+1}i_X\omega^{n+1},$$
the last equality is derived by induction on the integer $n$.

Since $\omega$ is non-degenerate on $V$, then $\omega^{n+1}\neq 0$ and since $X$ is transverse to $M$, one has $i_X\omega^{n+1}\neq 0$. Therefore, with our computation $\alpha\wedge(\mathrm{d}\alpha)^n\neq 0$, whence the result. $\Box$

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^{2n+2}$, $\omega:=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}\mathrm{d}x_i\wedge\mathrm{d}y_i$, $X=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}(x_i\mathrm{d}x_i+y_i\mathrm{d}y_i)$ and $M=\mathbb{S}^{2n+1}$, then:

- $(V,\omega)$ is a symplectic manifold,
- $M$ is an hypersurface of $V$,
- $X$ is transverse to $M$, since if $x\in S^{2n+1}$, $\langle X_x,x\rangle\neq 0$, so that $X_x\not\in T_xS^{2n+1}$.

Furthermore, one has the following equality:
$$i_X\omega=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(x_i\mathrm{d}y_i-y_i\mathrm{d}x_i)=\frac{1}{2}\alpha_{\mathrm{sph}},$$
so that $\mathcal{L}_X\omega=\omega$ and $X$ is a Liouville vector field of $V$. Whence, $\frac{1}{2}\alpha_{\textrm{sph}}$ is a contact structure on $S^{2n+1}$.